# Apache Spark: Fixing the timestamp format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a csv file and append it to a table. For the date column it throws `Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` exception.

I went through a couple of solutions but none worked for me.

I am trying to use a `udf` but it is throwing an exception :

```
Schema for type java.util.Date is not supported
```

Here is what I have tried :

```
val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
val toDate = udf[Date, String](dateFormat.parse(_))
val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("id", LongType, nullable=true), StructField("name", StringType, nullable=true), StructField("date_issued", TimestampType, nullable=true)))
var df = spark.read.schema(schema).csv("./data/test.csv")
var df2 = df.withColumn("date_issued", toDate(df("date_issued")))
df2.show()

df2.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db", "card", connectionProperties)
```

Comment: Try use `java.sql.date` instead `java.util.date`

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` returns `java.util.date`

Comment: updated my answer, please check it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is , need to convert the util date to sql date.

Try the code below.

```
def convertToDate(dateTime: String): Date = {

    val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
    val utilDate = formatter.parse(dateTime)
    new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime)
  }
```

Then convert this function as UDF.

```
val toDate = udf(convertToDate(_: String))
```